# Getting flask model objects to javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

For context, I'm coding a student-personalized weekly calendar and I have made a database using flask-sqlalchemy where I store all my lessons and their information. My current goal is to link the database with my html table.

So I have a class Lessons in models.py which I filled with data and I have no problem using it in my html or python code, but I would like to use it in a javascript function and it seems so complex just to link both.

From what I've read, Ajax could be a solution to my issue but after many tries I couldn't get to anything. I jsonify my list of Lessons but when I receive it in my ajax function it's unusable. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My js function:

```js
/**
* Displays the user's lessons
*/
function displayLessons(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get_lessons',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(lessons) {
            for(lesson in lessons){
                // I'll need to get the user too but that's for later
                if(lesson.years == user.year && lesson.studies == user.studies){
                    // haven't tried this out yet but the idea is there
                    document.getElementById(lesson.jour+'-'+lesson.start_hour).textContent = lesson.title
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

My route:

```py
@app.route('/get_lessons', methods=['GET'])
def get_lessons():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lessons = Lessons.query.all()
        return jsonify(lessons)
```

note: I'm a beginner and this is my first post, my description might not be clear enough in which case I'll be more than happy to answer your questions.

Comment: Are you sure you actually call the get_lessons function?

Comment: Yes I think so, I wrote alert(lessons) before the for loop and I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...

Comment: OK, that's weird. What does Lessons.query.all() return?

Comment: the def __repr__(self) that I defined for the class for each lesson, which is in this form: [<Lessons id: 1,studies: computer science, years: Year 1, title: economics, start_hour: 8:30>,<Lessons id:2,...>,<Lessons id:3,...>,...]

Comment: Is it normal that I get [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] when I enter http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_lessons ?

Comment: I think what's happening is that you're trying to convert that array into a string. Then `{}` becomes `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing my route to:

```py
@app.route('/get_lessons', methods=['GET'])
def get_lessons():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lessons = Lessons.query
        return jsonify(list(map(lambda x: x.to_dict(), lessons)))
```

I just had to `pip install sqlalchemy-serializer`
and in my models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin
```

change: `class Lessons(db.Model, SerializerMixin):`